# Как передать ключ Api для Yandex Wheather в Retrofit

Tags: java, kotlin, retrofit2

Есть интерфейс, не совсем понимаю как правильно передать API ключ Weather Yandex. `response.body()` возвращает `null` .

Как это сделать?

```
public interface WheatherService {
@Headers("X-Yandex-API-Key: 2cd81cb61cd15cb869c45aa0379f0f08")
@GET("/v1/forecast?")
Call<Data> getWheatherNow(@Query("lat") String lat, @Query("lon") String lon); }
```

Comment: Эх, ключ скомпрометировали...

Comment: Мне не жалко) Он вам в любом случае ничего не даст

Comment: добавьте [logging-interceptor](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-logging-interceptor) и смотрите в logcat'е что отправляется и что приходит. В `onResponse` так-то нужно ещё проверять на `response.isSuccessful()`, если false, то ошибку можно получить через `response.errorBody()`

Answer (score 2):

Если будете добавлять Headers в билдере при создании okHTTP клиента, то все будет работать.